# How do I detect the user-set screen zoom level in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

I'm trying to find a way in Kotlin to detect the level of display zoom a user has set on their device. I currently have two image buttons with labels off to one side sitting side by side in a LinearLayout. The labels wrap mid-word if the display zoom is set past a certain threshold. What I'd like to do is detect the zoom level (or whatever it's called) and stack them vertically if the text is over a certain size so users with less than ideal eyesight can read them properly. Is this possible in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

[DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html#DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE) exists specifically for this purpose. Compare that to your current densityDpi.

Comment: This will not work for Samsung devices where the resolution can be changed. On Samsung devices with zoom at default value, the DENSITY_DEVICE_STABLE will be less then the actual dpi ( expected to be equal).

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the values I needed in the `configuration` namespace. There are two user settings that are effecting the layout, Font Scale and Display Zoom, both of which can be set independently from one another.

```
val config = resources.configuration
val fontScale = config.fontScale
val screenWidth = config.screenWidthDp
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a [FlexboxLayout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) which kind of does what you're welling to achieve here.

However if you insist on using a LinearLayout and invert it's direction depending on weather your text fits there or not, you can use a [BoringLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/BoringLayout.html) which helps you to calculate the required width to draw a certain text e.g. the following code tells how much space `SomeText` requires to get drawn using a paint with the `textSize=20 SP`. So depending on this value you can decide how to set the orientation of your LinearLayout

```
val paint = TextPaint().apply {
            textSize = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20f, context.resources.displayMetrics)
        }
BoringLayout.getDesiredWidth("SomeText", paint)
```